# Reducing/summarising multiple tables with SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    saleid INT,
    saledateid INT,
    saleamount DECIMAL(12,2)
);

CREATE TABLE salelines (
    salelineid INT,
    saleid INT,
    quantity INT,
    unitamount DECIMAL(12,2)
);
```

If I wanted to calculate total sales per day:

```
SELECT sum(quantity * unitamount)
FROM sales
JOIN salelines USING (saleid)
GROUP BY saledateid;
```

In most cases `sales.saleamount` is the sum of the sale lines for that sale. But in some cases the `saleamount` is adjusted which is why we store it separately. So the actual total sales per day would be:

```
SELECT sum(saleamount)
FROM sales
GROUP BY saledateid;
```

However, I need both of these in the same query for a materialised view, the following won't work because a sale may be made of more than one sale line.

```
SELECT sum(quantity * unitamount), sum(saleamount)
FROM sales
JOIN salelines USING (saleid)
GROUP BY saledateid;
```

How do I do this? I am using PostgreSQL, but I'd rather a solution thats SQL-compliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is by adding a sequential number to the sales lines.  Then you can use conditional aggregation to choose only one value:

```
SELECT saledateid, sum(sl.quantity * sl.unitamount),
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then s.saleamount end)
FROM sales s JOIN
     (SELECT sl.*, row_number() over (partition by saleid order by saleid) as seqnum
      FROM salelines sl
     ) sl
     USING (saleid)
GROUP BY saledateid;
```

`row_number()` is an ANSI standard function and available in most databases.  Your question originally had MySQL as a tag, but it is not available there.

Comment: For brevity I didn't include that `salelines` has a `sequence INT`, so I was able to use `sum(case when sequence = 1 then saleamount end)`. Thanks!

Comment: @ElliotChance . . . That will work in MySQL as well.